# Is there a isomorphism $M_n(C(X))\cong C(X)\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, banach-algebras

Is there an isomorphism $M_n(C(X))\cong C(X)\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as $C^*$-algebras? And if yes how does it look?

Comment: The matrix norm on the right and some tensor norm on the right

Comment: How do you define the norm exactly on both side ?